# Convert C code into F#

Tags: f#

I am looking to convert the following C code into F# (this is the fast inverse square root algorithm):

```c
float Q_rsqrt( float number )
{
    long i;
    float x2, y;

    x2 = number * 0.5F;
    y  = number;
    i  = * ( long * ) &y;   // Extract bit pattern
    i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );   
    y  = * ( float * ) &i;  // Convert back to float.
    y  = y * ( 1.5F - ( x2 * y * y ) );   

    return y;
}
```

Comment: So which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Here you are just use search engine: [solution](http://fssnip.net/9M).

Comment: Also, on modern hardware (and particularly in .net) this is probably slower than the naive method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should do some research. Then if you stuck specify with what you have problem.
Here is [solution by Kit Eason](http://tryfs.net/snippets/snippet-9M).

```
let fastInvSqrt (n : float32) : float32 =
    let MAGIC_NUMBER : int32 = 0x5f3759df 
    let THREE_HALVES = 1.5f
    let x2 = n * 0.5f
    let i = MAGIC_NUMBER - (System.BitConverter.ToInt32(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(n), 0) >>> 1)
    let y = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(i), 0)
    y * (THREE_HALVES - (x2 * y * y))

// Examples:
let x = fastInvSqrt 4.0f
// Output: val x : float32 = 0.499153584f
let x' = 1. / sqrt(4.0)
// Output: val x' : float = 0.5
```

Comment: While this probably works the fact that it allocates two byte array per inverse square in practice it's probably not that fast. One can avoid byte allocation by manual layout of structs but then there's the challenge of endianess.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to performance and low-level optimization it is often a good idea to measure before and after. The fast-inverse trick is very cool but it's approximates the inverse square and the question is if tricky code like this is truely necessary these days (in the DOOM days when float performace was crap the trick was amazing).

Anyway so I built a simple performance test bench in order to compare the trivial implementation with the solution provided by Kit Eason/lad2025 and another one that doesn't allocate byte arrays.

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<Literal>]
let MAGIC_NUMBER : int32 = 0x5f3759df 
[<Literal>]
let THREE_HALVES  = 1.5F
[<Literal>]
let HALF          = 0.5F

[<Literal>]
let OUTER         = 1000
[<Literal>]
let INNER         = 10000

let inline invSqr (x : float32) : float32 = 1.F / sqrt x

let fInvSqr (x : float32) : float32 =
  let x2 = x * 0.5f
  // Allocates two byte arrays creating GC pressure ==> hurts performance
  let i = MAGIC_NUMBER - (BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(x), 0) >>> 1)
  let y = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(i), 0)
  y * (THREE_HALVES - (x2 * y * y))

// Susceptible to race conditions & endianess issues
[<StructLayout (LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type Bits =
  struct
    [<FieldOffset(0)>]
    val mutable f: float32
    [<FieldOffset(0)>]
    val mutable i: int32
  end   

let mutable bits = Bits ()

let fInvSqr2 (x : float32) : float32 =
  let x2 = x * 0.5F
  bits.f <- x
  let i = MAGIC_NUMBER - (bits.i >>> 1)
  bits.i <- i
  let y = bits.f
  y * (THREE_HALVES - (x2 * y * y))


let timeIt n (a : unit -> 'T) : int64 * 'T = 
  let r = a ()

  let sw = Stopwatch ()

  sw.Start ()

  for i = 1 to n do
    ignore <| a ()

  sw.Stop ()

  sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, r

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

  let testCases =
    [|
      "invSqr"    , fun () -> 
                      let mutable sum = 0.F
                      for x = 1 to INNER do 
                        sum <- sum + invSqr (float32 x)
                      sum
      "fInvSqr"   , fun () ->
                      let mutable sum = 0.F
                      for x = 1 to INNER do 
                        sum <- sum + fInvSqr (float32 x)
                      sum
      "fInvSqr2"  , fun () ->
                      let mutable sum = 0.F
                      for x = 1 to INNER do 
                        sum <- sum + fInvSqr2 (float32 x)
                      sum
    |]

  for name, action in testCases do
    printfn "Running %s %d times..." name (OUTER*INNER)
    let elapsed, result = timeIt OUTER action
    printfn "... it took %d ms product result: %f" elapsed result

  0
```

The performance test result on my machine:

```
Running invSqr 10000000 times...
... it took 78 ms product result: 198.544600
Running fInvSqr 10000000 times...
... it took 311 ms product result: 198.358200
Running fInvSqr2 10000000 times...
... it took 49 ms product result: 198.358200
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So we see that fInvSqr is actually 3 times slower than the trivial solution, most likely because of the byte allocation. In addition the cost of GC is hidden in these numbers and might add non-deterministic performance degration.

fInvSqr2 seems to perform slightly better but there are drawbacks here as well

1. The result is off by 0.1%
2. The `Bits` trick is susceptible to race conditions (fixable)
3. The `Bits` trick is suspectible to endian issues (if you are run the program on a CPU with different endianess it might break)

Is the performance gains worth the drawbacks? Since a program probably is not just built up from inverse square operations the effective performance gain might be much smaller in reality. I have a hard time imagining a scenario where I would so presurres for performance I opt for the fast inverse trick today but then it all depends on your context.

Comment: The solution I proposed has not best performance comparing to default `1.0f / sqrt(x)`. I checked also `x ** (-0.5f)` and `Math.pow(x, -0.5)` which are even slower. Maybe the best way is to use specialized external Math Numerical Library.